# Link conversions what fails here, to give all 3 links thumbnail from Youtube?

Tags: php, youtube, strpos

Following code gives youtube thumbnails to text which is posted as youtube link, why it seems illegal that it doesn't allow htttps://www. instead it brings output as link that is in variable $text.

$text = "link from web"...

```
if (strpos($text,'https://www.youtube.com') !== false) {

$domas = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="'.$file.'">
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube_id2.'/default.jpg" width="100" height="100"></img>
</a>';

} 

if (strpos($text,'https://www.yout') !== false) {

$domas = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="'.$file.'">
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube_id2.'/default.jpg" width="100" height="100"></img>
</a>';

} 
if (strpos($text,'youtu.be') === false) {

$domas = $text;

} 
    echo $domas;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly you want to achieve??

`strpos(originalText,findThis)` returns the `number or false`. Number - integer which basically is the the starting position of string/char you are looking in it. For example your original text is "Ronalds" and you are searching for "R", it will return integer 0, because the char R is in the 0th position (think about the string as an array - it is 0th elementh). And so on. If you are looking for char "E" - and there is definetely not such a char in your original text, then the function will return `boolean false`.

in your condition it could look like this - if in original text somewhere there is https://www.youtube.com then inner part will be processed. (Where does this $youtube_id2 comes from in your code?)

Isnt it `switch-case` style you`re looking for your conception here?

Comment: integer ? it's already string where I check there. switch case could work.

Comment: One more thing is that the first and second conditions both will be valid - if original text has 'http://www.youtube.com' in it (first condition), then it definetely has 'http://www.yout' in it (second condition). And in such case code inside of second condition will take over of code in first condition.

Comment: Come on. Try echo strpos("Ronalds","s"). Result will be 6. Integer.